# Shiny: associate a slider with a group clicked on in a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

### UPDATE

I think I managed to make it work - at least now I know how to fetch the group information from the clicked on point. See [this `gist`](https://gist.github.com/KKulma/e02287b9f83715cebbd3e3f1b1441fab)

## INTRO

I'm building a Shiny app where I want to display a backlog volume for all the products dealt with by a given team. The backlog is driven by 2 factors: number of `new` items coming in and `closed` coming out, specific to each product. Additionally, each product has an associated `productivity` value (needed in a different part of the app).

## QUESTION

I want to be able to: 
1) click on the specific product and see the table being filtered to the chosen product and

2) modify the underlying assumptions by adjusting `new`, `closed` and `productivity` % sliders that would apply only to selected product.

3) Those changes in underlying assumptions would be then reflected in the plot.

The suggested rule behind this can be found in the commented part of `react_df()` definition. The plot can be built using any `shiny`-friendly package, not necessarily `ggplot2`.

## WHAT I'VE TRIED

I'm new to Shiny. I tried to use `tooltip` functionality and started looking into `plotOutput` arguments for actions associated with double-click, but couldn't get it to work: examples shown in RStudio resources on interactive plots (e.g. [this one](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html) or [this one](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/selecting-rows-of-data.html) use scatterplots and retrieve x or y values rather than group info. You can see my `gist` [here](https://gist.github.com/KKulma/e829fc18080862ef926f86ee32cb309d).

Any helpful tips will be welcome!

## THE APP

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(DT)

new_vals <- c(50, 100, 200)
data <- data.frame(
  date = rep(as.Date(c('2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01')),  4),
  country = c(rep('UK', 3), rep('US', 9)),
  team = c(rep('team A', 3),rep('team B', 6), rep('team C', 3)),
  prod = c(rep('prod1', 3),rep('prod2', 3), rep('prod3', 3), rep('prod4', 3)),
  new = c(new_vals, new_vals+50, new_vals - 50, new_vals+100),
  closed = c(new_vals-20, new_vals+30, new_vals - 30, new_vals+80), 
  productivity = rep(c(50, 70, 80, 40), each = 3),
  orig_backlog = rep(c(100, NA, NA), 4)
)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(
    uiOutput("edit_country"),
    uiOutput("edit_team")
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(4, 
               wellPanel(uiOutput("edit_productivity"))
        ),
        column(4,
               wellPanel(uiOutput("edit_new"))
        ),
        column(4, 
               wellPanel(uiOutput("edit_closed"))
        ))),
    fluidPage(plotOutput("ts_plot")),
    fluidPage(dataTableOutput("table"))

  )
)


server <- function(input, output) {


  react_data <- reactive({
    data %>% 
      filter(country == input$country,
             team == input$team) %>% 
      group_by(country, team, prod) %>% 
      mutate(
        #new = new + round((closed*input$new)/100,0),
        #closed = closed + round((closed*input$closed)/100,0),
        #productivity = productivity + round((closed*input$productivity)/100,0),
        new_minus_closed = new - closed,
        backlog = orig_backlog[1] + cumsum(new_minus_closed),
        backlog = ifelse(backlog < 0, 0, backlog)
      )  %>% 
      select(-orig_backlog) %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      replace(., is.na(.), 0)
  })


  output$edit_country <- renderUI({
    selectInput("country", "Choose Country",
                choices = unique(data$country),
                selected = 'US',
                multiple = FALSE)
    })

  output$edit_team <- renderUI({
    selectInput("team", "Choose Team",
                choices = data %>% 
                  filter(country == input$country) %>% 
                  select(team) %>% 
                  unique() %>% 
                  pull(team),
                selected = 'team B',
                multiple = FALSE)
  })


  output$edit_new <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("new", "Edit New",
                min = -100, max = 100, post  = " %",
                value = 0)
  })



  output$edit_productivity <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("productivity", "Edit Productivity",
                min = -100, max = 100, post  = " %",
                value = 0)

  })

  output$edit_closed <- renderUI({
    sliderInput("closed", "Edit Closed",
                min = -100, max = 100, post  = " %",
                value = 0)

  })

  output$ts_plot <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(react_data(), aes(date, backlog, group = prod, color = prod)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_line() +
      labs(x = '') +
      theme_minimal()
    })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable({
    react_data() %>%
                    select(date, prod, new, closed, productivity) %>%
                    as.data.frame()

  })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: What have you tried? There's a whole section of documentation on this: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-interaction.html

Comment: @Spacedman: I now added more info on what I've tried to my question. Does it really deserve a down-vote?

Comment: "Does not show any research effort" is a reason for a downvote. Took me about two minutes to find the docs on plot interaction. Even things you cant get to work are useful in a question - maybe you were 90% of the way there?

Comment: @Kasia Kulma: Can you please elaborate on the expected behaviour? What exactly should happen after you click a point/trace in the plot?

Comment: @Spacedman: thanks for pointing me into the right direction, but I still have problems retrieving group info from the plot. See my gist now added to the question.

Comment: @ismirsehregal: I now updated my question by adding a more detailed explanation of expected behaviour. Hope it's clearer now!

Comment: OK @Spacedman and @ismirsehregal: I think I got it now, see the question update with the solution `gist`. Thanks for looking into this and giving me useful pointers!

Comment: Thanks, much better now. Have you considered directly editing the table? In the end you want to be able to edit every single row of the table?

Comment: Ok, great. Please provide your gist as an own answer here.